# Laravel 8: order by associated table column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by, relationship

I need to order my query by a related table column:

I have a parent table `flyer` and the child table `flyer_statistics`. In the child theres an column called `pageview_counter`,
(where is count up every page-call of the `flyer`).

I want to get the top 10 of the `flyer`, descending with the value of `flyer_statistics.pageview_counter`.

I tried this but it doesn't sort:

```
$flyer = Flyer::with(['flyerStatistics' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('pageview_counter', 'desc');
}])->limit(10)->get();
```

`Flyer` model:

```
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'affiliate_id',
        'flyer_ref_code',
        'flyer_active'
    ];

    public function flyerStatistics() {
        return $this->hasOne(FlyerStatistics::class, 'flyer_id');
    }
}
```

`FlyerStatistics` model:

```
{
    use HasFactory;

     /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'flyer_id',
        'pageview_counter'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the flyer that owns the phone.
     */
    public function flyer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Flyer::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

What is my mistake?

**Edit:**

This would working:

```
Flyer::join('flyer_statistics', 'flyers.id', '=', 'flyer_statistics.flyer_id')
    ->select('affiliate_id','pageview_counter')
    ->orderBy('pageview_counter', 'desc')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

But is that valid in case of correct using laravel relationships?

Comment: Using Query builder, second approach is correct. Relationship is supported by laravel eloquent but it doesn't mean using query builder is not a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

If its not working, you can sort it on your foreach. For example

```
@foreach ($flyer->flyerStatistics()->orderBy('pageview_counter', 'DESC')->get() as $flyer)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been thinking about it too, but imaging there are 2 million table entrys and you have to foreach them. That's not really performant, I think. I need an sql query solution.

Comment: You can pass the orderBy after the `->limit()` can you do it?

Comment: It seems there is no access to the child model outside the `with()` function. It throws an error: `Unknown column 'pageview_counter'`.

Comment: This is working: `Flyer::join('flyer_statistics', 'flyers.id', '=', 'flyer_statistics.flyer_id')->orderBy('pageview_counter', 'desc')->limit(10)->get();`, but is that valid in case of correct using laravel relationships?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereHas` instead of `with`.

```html
$flyer = Flyer::whereHas('flyerStatistics', function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('pageview_counter', 'desc');
})->limit(10)->get();
```

It should work.

Comment: That did not work. It is not sorted, nor i have access to `pageview_counter`.